# Detect if user browser-height >= page body-height

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

I am running in a bit of a problem here trying to figure out this one.
I already coded a jquery function that detects when the user hits the bottom of the page and trigger an function.
Now, while this works alright for the most common screen-sizes, it will not work when the user has a screen so big that sees the entire page at once, rendering the previous function useless.

What I am trying to achive is the fallback for those cases, how can I tell if the user has such a screensize that will trigger the function and leave the rest to the other?

Better explained: How to detect if the user browser-height is equal or greater than the page body height?

Sorry if this looks a bit confusing.

PS: The following code is the one I am using when the browser-height is smaller than the page body-height.

```
    if ($('body').height() <= ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop())) {
        //run function here when the browser-height is smaller than
        //the page's height and it has reached the bottom
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    if ($(document).height() <= $(window).height() ) { }
```

$(document).height(); // returns height of HTML document

Comment: Well, this is awkward, both of you answered exactly what I wanted but I will choose your answer because you were first (sorry jorgebg)
Also I love it, simple and direct, thanks both of you.

Comment: Also, on a side note, if I want it to detect a smaller height than the real one, can I just subtract from the document.height?
Ex:
        if (($(document).height() - 100) <= $(window).height() ) { }

Answer (score 3):

Use document height instead.

```
if ($(document).height() <= $(window).height())
{..}
```